# Subtracting 1 from count before getting average

Tags: java

Below is a code I have written to give me the largest and smallest integer while also finding the average of the integers entered. My problem is that it is counting the negative number when finding the average. I need it to not count the negative number. Maybe subtracting one from the count? Or an if else statement?

import java.util.Scanner;

public class LargeSmallAverage {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int smallest, largest, sum, count;
    sum = 0;
    count = 0;
    System.out.println("Please enter a series of positive numbers. Enter a negative number to exit program.");

    int positive = in.nextInt();
    smallest = largest = positive;

    while (positive > 0) 
    {
        if (smallest > positive) 
            smallest = positive;

        if (largest < positive) 
            largest = positive;


        sum = sum + positive;
        count++;
        positive = in.nextInt();

    }

double average = sum / count;

    System.out.println("The smallest number entered was " + smallest);
    System.out.println("The largest number entered was " + largest);
    System.out.println("The average of all positive numbers entered is " + average);
}
```

}

OUTPUT:

Please enter a series of positive numbers. Enter a negative number to exit program.
2
20
10
5
10
2
-5
The smallest number entered was 2
The largest number entered was 20
The average of all positive numbers entered is 8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  double average = ((double) sum) / count;
```

You used integer division 49 / 6 = 8.

Comment: WOW!! Thank you. I wasn't catching that easy mistake and neither did my professor. Thanks a ton!!!